# JSreact child component error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I edited code that was working perfectly fine, until I added new code to make the button clicking work from video to video. I just can't find the error, and the terminal is not picking it up either.

Can someone tell me why the ./video_list_item.js is not being recognized anymore?

Attached is the parent, and 2 child components, though I have 5 total components the error is definitely only in one of the two.

index.js

```js
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import SearchBar from './components/searchbar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';
const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyAi1CzVpifuFUDVQf3dzrTu3mwJDP2n8r8';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  //Do i expect this component to play any type of state? aka pass props
  this.state= { 
   videos: [],
   selectedVideo:null

  };
      //  ^proper name can be anything


  YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (videos) => {
// console.log(data);
  this.setState({ videos:videos,
   selectedVideo: videos[0]
   });
 });  // this.setState({videos : vidoos});  
}
 render (){
 return (
 <div>
  <SearchBar />
  <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo} />
  <VideoList 
  onVideoSelect={selectedVideo => this.setState({selectedVideo})  }
  videos={this.state.videos} /> 
            
 </div>
  ); 
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

video_list.js

```js
//video list file. JS.react
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

const VideoList = (props) => {
 //    ^props is made args here because videos var is passed
 //    in index.js into VideoList function(with state).
const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {

  return (
 <VideoListItem 
  onVideoSelect={props.onVideoSelect}
  key={video.etag} 
  video ={video} />
  ); 
 });
 return (
  <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
  {videoItems}
  </ul>
 );
 
};

export default VideoList;
```

video_list.item.js

```js
//video list item file. JS.react
import React from 'react'; 

const VideoListItem = ({video, onVideoSelect}) => {
 const imageUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
 // can see this in console log 
 return (
 <li onClick={() => onVideoSelect{video} }className="list-group-item">
 <div className ="video-list media">
  <div className ="media-left">
  <img className="media-object" src = {imageUrl}/>

  </div>


  <div className="media-body"> 

  <div className="media-heading"> {video.snippet.title} </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </li>
 );
};

export default VideoListItem;
```

I can post the error message I get in the dev tools, but it literally just says one thing. This is the error message => Cannot find module "./video_list_item"

Also, no files were moved around at all, the code was edited and that created the error message. Thanks for anyone who sincerely answers this question!

Comment: don't you have the videolistitem in the `./components` directory?

Comment: Could you show us your directory structure?

Comment: sure, I will add it in a few moments.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to edit the above post.

Comment: The directory is src file, index.js and then components directory. 
All the components are in the components directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<li onClick={() => onVideoSelect{video} }className="list-group-item">`

The error is the `{video}` should actually be in parenthesis like so `(video)`.

correct code is:
`<li onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video) }className="list-group-item">.`

Note: The `{}` makes it so the child component is not recognized by the parent for some strange reason. Thanks to all those who helped in answering!